# How to video call

Tags: applications, video-calling

Hi im new to ask a question. I have 7 inch tab with 1GB ram 4G volte android 6.0. And i want to make the video call without any 3rd party app. There is no icon only sms icon shown. How can i make a video call. Can we have some app which can enable the feature to call directly. or if any additional app added and make the feature directly call without using other 3rd party app (skype, whatsapp, etc.) Any help or suggestion. Thanks

Comment: What makes an app 3rd party?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this for a G903F with CSC Options to enable IP and video calls and the needed menus.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ma.wanam.cscexpert

[image: contact]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your native dialer?

Comment: i do not have samsung tablet. The app works with samsung mobile only.  i have iball its not working in my tablet any other method

Comment: Is there something similar?

Comment: @lemrm i did not get what you mean.. I said i have iball 4G tab and i want to make direct calling without any 3rd party app. Can you plz explain me now after installing its asking for search what should i search for?. Plz explain in detail. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you have CSC on iball. Could you see this folder `/system/csc/feature.xml` with ADB